# read and show raw depth image in matlab

Tags: matlab, color-depth

I have a set of .raw depth images. The image format is 500X290 with 32 bytes per pixel. When I open them with IrfanView image viewer I see the depth image correctly like this:
[displayed image in IrfanView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdKgw.png)

Now I want to read and display the same depth image in Matlab. I do like this:

```
 FID=fopen('depthImage.raw','r');
 DepthImage = fread(FID,[290,500],'bit32');
 fclose(FID);
 colormap winter;
 imshow(DepthImage);
```

DepthImage is a 290X500 type double matrix.
what I get from this code is this image:
[displayed image in Matlab viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfwpd.jpg)

when I change fread parameter from 'bit32' to 'bit24' I get this:
[displayed image in Matlab with bit24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ3yE.jpg)

I guess each element in DepthImage contains 32 bits where each 8 bits corresponds to R,G,B and D values. but how can I read the image correctly and display it like the one in IrfanView?

the raw file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aHcRmMKvi5gtodahR5l_Dx8SbK_920c5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be an issue with image metadata header, like "date and time of the shot", "camera type". Open your image with notepad++ to check for "date and time". If you upload your original raw image, it will be easier to try things.

Upd: Ok, this is something. Check if it helps

```
 FID=fopen('camera00000000000014167000.raw','r');
 DepthImage = fread(FID,290*500*4,'int8');
 DepthImageR = DepthImage(1:4:end);
 DepthImageG = DepthImage(2:4:end);
 DepthImageB = DepthImage(3:4:end);
 DepthImageD = DepthImage(4:4:end);

 dataR = reshape(DepthImageR, 500,290);
 dataG = reshape(DepthImageG, 500,290);
 dataB = reshape(DepthImageB, 500,290);
 dataD = reshape(DepthImageD, 500,290); % all equal to 64 - useless

 figure()
 subplot(2,2,1)
 image(dataR)
 subplot(2,2,2)
 image(dataG)
 subplot(2,2,3)
 image(dataB)
 subplot(2,2,4)

 data = zeros(500,290,3);
 data(:,:,1) = dataR;
 data(:,:,2) = dataG;
 data(:,:,3) = dataB;

 image(data)
```

Comment: in IrfanView I open it with header size equal to 0 bytes which means there is no header. The .raw file loads like a .bin file and nothing is understandable when its opened with notepad++. I upload the original image.

Comment: you have the file now under the post.

Comment: thanks it worked for me. I did not know how to separate R,G,B from each other. The way you did it is great.

Comment: do you have any idea why R and G channels are only noise?

Comment: may be camera parameters need adjustment? I have experience with Basler machine vision camera. There are a lot of tuning possibilities in their software. What camera do you use? Another idea is that image might have been made with a blue filter.

Comment: How IrfanView produced the abovementioned image and we couldn't. It considered the raw data as 32 bits ABRG and produced that image.

Comment: I figured out that the captured data is not RGBD values. They are point cloud data. when I assume that is XYZI (x,y,z and intensity maybe!) and I draw it as a point cloud. I don't get point cloud of the captured scene but a weird structure: https://imgur.com/a/bu8TgmM

Comment: what could be the potential problem here... How can I get the point cloud. Am I reading the data incorrectly?! any idea